# What are the advantages of cpio over tar, zip, etc?

Tags: tar, archive, cpio

With cpio, you need to direct a list of files into cpio's standard input, whereas with tools such as tar, zip, etc, it's possible to recursively archive a directory (or multiple directories).

I understand it's considered good manners and/or best practice to archive a directory so that if you give your *.tar or *.zip archive to somebody else, when they extract it, they don't get a splattering of files all over the place in whatever directory they're extracting it to.

If other archive tools can archive both files and directories and cpio can only archive files, what are the advantages and/or use cases of cpio?

Comment: regarding your title: why *should* there be any advantages? It's a legacy tool. The `man cpio` page even starts with **WARNING** *The cpio utility is considered LEGACY based on POSIX specification.  Users are encouraged to use other archiving tools for archive creation.*.

Comment: by the way, ZIP is not an option, usually, because it simply doesn't support file ownership and access attributes. It's a fine tool if you're using MS-DOS... which is exactly what it was made for.

Comment: If it's legacy and discouraged from use, why is it required for the LFCS exam?

Comment: Because exams are often decades behind reality. There's no good reason. Also, this seems to be your *real* question! So please add that to your question's text by [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/656049/edit) it!

Comment: POSIX documents *cpio* as a required feature of [pax](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html).

Comment: As for *"list of files into cpio"* - that is a very unicy way of doing things. `find` is as old as `cpio` and they were designed to be used together https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/FormatCpio - think of it as *modules*, *functions* or even *objects* in programming ;), As for the format used in `intiramfs`, `rpm`, pax et. None the less; the *advantages* vs *that it is used* (In regards to LFCS) are two different topics.

Comment: @ThomasDickey POSIX mandates that `pax` supports the `cpio` archive format - not cpio the utility.

Comment: POSIX doesn't define tar except as a feature of pax.

Comment: The `cpio` archive format is seen as outdated and unfixable since every extension to support more meta data would require to introduce a new and incompatible archive format variant. AT&T preferred `cpio` only because there is an undocumented feature that allows `cpio` to install new versions of binaries without forcing running binaries to crash from that update. `star` is the only other `cpio` implementation that supports the undocumented install feature. BTW: `find | cpio` is slow because it enforces two `stat()` calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If other archive tools can archive both files and directories and cpio can only archive files, what are the advantages and/or use cases of cpio?

None. Fedora's `cpio` documentation discourages the use of CPIO:

```
__WARNING__
       The cpio utility is considered LEGACY based on POSIX specification.  Users are encouraged to use other archiving tools for archive creation.
```

There's really no advantages, unless you need to use a system for which CPIO exists, but TAR, mksquashfs, … don't. (Such systems do to the best of my knowledge *not* exist for the last 20 or so years.)

Some formats are simply stuck on cpio for reasons of legacy; .rpm is one of these. That's the only reason why you'd use cpio: Some decades-old software expects you to.

> If it's legacy and discouraged from use, why is it required for the LFCS exam?

Exams imitate real life, and typically, with a long delay between reality and examination. Also, often people designing tests are "old-school" because, well they were *there* when cpio was the only reliable way to exchange archives between different POSIX systems. But then again, Stéphane is right, Linux initrd is typically cpio!

Generally, "it's in a test, it must be relevant" is not inherently... true.

---

ZIP is not an option, usually, because it simply doesn't support file ownership and access attributes. It's a fine tool if you're using MS-DOS, which is exactly what it was made for. Even on modern Windows, files have more attributes that ZIP simply can't represent.

Comment: This actually clears it up quite nicely for me. Thank you, Marcus!

Comment: You're quite welcome, @KouroshTaheri-Golvarzi!

Comment: @Marcus Info-ZIP does support uids, gids etc., but they need to be restored explicitly (`unzip -X`). Use `zipinfo -v` to see all the information stored in the metadata.

Comment: ZIP as in PKWARE has *extra fields*. Unix Extra Field has been present since 1998. Also ZIP was in large made for saving *streams of data*. Also typically across multiple storage mediums. It has a central directory at end of archive which tells which disk etc a file is on. Thus unzip `foo` -> OK, insert disk `16` ... etc. E.g. https://opensource.apple.com/source/zip/zip-6/unzip/unzip/proginfo/extra.fld.auto.html

Comment: On which system or with which implementation of `cpio` do you see that legacy warning? It's not in the GNU cpio manual. Is it added by some Linux distribution? (that would be ironic as Linux initrds are typically in cpio format, though here that warning is about the tool/CLI, not the format; note that you can use `bsdtar` to create/extract cpio archives).

Comment: `zip` can store ownership (though not both username and userid like tar) and permissions, but not the full range of extended attributes of some systems, or hard links...

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas GNU cpio's `man cpio` on Fedora 34. And you're right, upstream https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/cpio.git/tree/doc/cpio.1 doesn't contain the warning!

Comment: The legacy warning is somewhat misleading as it implies that the `cpio` utility is part of POSIX.  The current and previous version of POSIX.1 did not specify either the `tar` or `cpio` utilities.

Comment: @fpmurphy interesting!

Comment: toned down my answer; I feel it's been a bit misleading (I've been misled by the manpage myself!)